# Lucene .NET search results

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, lucene, lucene.net

I'm using this code to index:

```
public void IndexEmployees(IEnumerable<Employee> employees)
{
    var indexPath = GetIndexPath();
    var directory = FSDirectory.Open(indexPath);

    var indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29), true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);

    foreach (var employee in employees)
    {
        var document = new Document();
        document.Add(new Field("EmployeeId", employee.EmployeeId.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO, Field.TermVector.NO));
        document.Add(new Field("Name", employee.FirstName + " " + employee.LastName, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.NO));
        document.Add(new Field("OfficeName", employee.OfficeName, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.NO));
        document.Add(new Field("CompetenceRatings", string.Join(" ", employee.CompetenceRatings.Select(cr => cr.Name)), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.NO));

        indexWriter.AddDocument(document);
    }

    indexWriter.Optimize();
    indexWriter.Close();

    var indexReader = IndexReader.Open(directory, true);
    var spell = new SpellChecker.Net.Search.Spell.SpellChecker(directory);
    spell.ClearIndex();

    spell.IndexDictionary(new LuceneDictionary(indexReader, "Name"));
    spell.IndexDictionary(new LuceneDictionary(indexReader, "OfficeName"));
    spell.IndexDictionary(new LuceneDictionary(indexReader, "CompetenceRatings"));
}

public DirectoryInfo GetIndexPath()
{
    return new DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/App_Data/EmployeeIndex/"));
}
```

And this code to find results (as well as suggestions):

```
public SearchResult Search(DirectoryInfo indexPath, string[] searchFields, string searchQuery)
{
    var directory = FSDirectory.Open(indexPath);

    var standardAnalyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29);

    var indexReader = IndexReader.Open(directory, true);
    var indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);

    var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_29, searchFields, standardAnalyzer);
    //parser.SetDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.OR);
    var query = parser.Parse(searchQuery);

    var hits = indexSearcher.Search(query, null, 5000);

    return new SearchResult
                {
                    Suggestions = FindSuggestions(indexPath, searchQuery),
                    LuceneDocuments = hits
                        .scoreDocs
                        .Select(scoreDoc => indexSearcher.Doc(scoreDoc.doc))
                        .ToArray()
                };
}

public string[] FindSuggestions(DirectoryInfo indexPath, string searchQuery)
{
    var directory = FSDirectory.Open(indexPath);

    var spell = new SpellChecker.Net.Search.Spell.SpellChecker(directory);

    var similarWords = spell.SuggestSimilar(searchQuery, 20);

    return similarWords;
}

var searchResult = Search(GetIndexPath(), new[] { "Name", "OfficeName", "CompetenceRatings" }, "admin*");
```

Simple queries like: admin or admin* doesnt give me any results. I know that there is an employee with that name. I want to be able to find James Jameson if I search for James.

Thanks!

Comment: How are we supposed to know how you are searching unless you show us the code where you invoke Search()? More specifically, what parameters are you passing on.

Comment: jishi: Sorry, i've included the call to the search method in the question: var searchResult = Search(GetIndexPath(), new[] { "Name", "OfficeName", "CompetenceRatings" }, "admin*");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing. You have to commit the changes to the index.

```
indexWriter.Optimize();
indexWriter.Commit(); //Add This
indexWriter.Close();
```

Edit#2 
Also, keep it simple until you get something that works.

Comment this stuff out.

```
//var indexReader = IndexReader.Open(directory, true);
//var spell = new SpellChecker.Net.Search.Spell.SpellChecker(directory);
//spell.ClearIndex();

//spell.IndexDictionary(new LuceneDictionary(indexReader, "Name"));
//spell.IndexDictionary(new LuceneDictionary(indexReader, "OfficeName"));
//spell.IndexDictionary(new LuceneDictionary(indexReader, "CompetenceRatings"));
```

Edit#3

The fields you are searching are probably not going to change often. I would include them in your search function.

```
string[] fields = new string[] { "Name", "OfficeName", "CompetenceRatings" };
```

The biggest reason I suggest this is that Fields are case-sensitive and sometimes you wont get any results and it's because you search the "name" field (which doesn't exist) instead of the "Name" field. Easier to spot the mistake this way.

Comment: It's this type of "error" that makes a person bang their head against a table.

Comment: Great, now I'm getting results. I'll do a bit of testing and see if it works as expected now. Thanks!

Comment: just a little remark, the close() method actually commits all changes to the index, so the call to commit here is not whats helping

Comment: The API states that commit() "Commits all pending changes" and close() "Commits all changes" What's a pending change versus a non-pending change?

Comment: Thanks SharpBarb. My code is running. I had one more problem, because the SpellChecker index was overwriting my original index. I've fixed that also. I want to keep the fields as a param, because i want to use the method to search multiple indexes.

Answer (score 2):

In my (limited) experience working with Lucene, I've found that you have to build up your own query in order to get "google" like behavior.  Here is what I do, YMMV, but it generates expected results in my application.  The basic idea is you combine a term query (exact match), a prefix query (anything that begins with the term), and a fuzzy query for each term in the search string.  The code below won't compile, but gives you the idea

```
Query GetQuery(string querystring)
{

   Search.Search.BooleanQuery query = new Search.Search.BooleanQuery();

   Search.Analysis.TokenStream tk = StandardAnalyzerInstance.TokenStream(null, new StringReader(querystring));
   Search.Analysis.Tokenattributes.TermAttribute ta = tk.GetAttribute(typeof(Search.Analysis.Tokenattributes.TermAttribute)) as Search.Analysis.Tokenattributes.TermAttribute;

    while (tk.IncrementToken())
    {
         string term = ta.Term();
         Search.Search.BooleanQuery bq = new Search.Search.BooleanQuery();
         bq.Add(new Search.Search.TermQuery(new Search.Index.Term("fieldToQuery", term)), Search.Search.BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
         bq.Add(new Search.Search.PrefixQuery(new Search.Index.Term("fieldToQuery", term)), Search.Search.BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
         bq.Add(new Search.Search.FuzzyQuery(new Search.Index.Term("fieldToQuery", term)), Search.Search.BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
         query.Add(bq, Search.Search.BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    }

    return query;
}
```

Comment: I've rewritten your code: http://pastebin.com/Kt4VqAtA (too long to paste here). However it doesnt give me any results. The line which invokes the method looks like this: var query = BuildQuery(standardAnalyzer, searchFields, searchQuery); and replaces the var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_29, searchFields, standardAnalyzer); var query = parser.Parse(searchQuery); part from the example above.

Comment: Try this:  http://pastebin.com/M2cpHrQe.  The only other thing I can think to change depends on our application - when adding the subqueries, I use MUST, meaning some form of each term must be in each field.  This may be too strict for your application, in which case you can modify the query to be less strict.

Comment: Joe, thanks for your suggestion. I'm still not able to get any results.

Comment: Joe, I ended up using a slightly modified method, from your sample. It gives me much better results. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That Parse() method is inherited. Have you tried utilizing the static methods that returns a Query object?

```
Parse(Version matchVersion, String[] queries, String[] fields, Analyzer analyzer)
```

Comment: I've updated the code to this: var query = MultiFieldQueryParser.Parse(Version.LUCENE_29,
    Enumerable.Repeat(searchQuery, searchFields.Length).ToArray(),
    searchFields,
    standardAnalyzer); I still don't get any results.

Comment: Then start by inspecting your index with Luke or equivalent and make sure that your index actually returns any result for any query.