# Matching a term that contains nested HTML

Tags: c#

I have been having trouble finding a solution to this problem.
I am parsing the content of a number of ebooks, finding specific terms and characters, marking the locations and lengths of each term.

A normal case would be something like this (excerpts from A Game of Thrones):

> "When he paused to look down, his head swam dizzily and he felt his fingers slipping. Bran cried out and clung for dear life."

If we are searching for the character "Bran", its location is 85 and length is 4. Easy enough.

My issue arises when there is a paragraph like this:

```html
<span height="-0em"><font size="7">D</font></span>aenerys Targaryen wed Khal Drogo
```

We need to match "Daenerys Targaryn". It is easy enough to strip the HTML and match the string, but in this example the result needs to include the HTML. Thus the expected result would here be would be location = 0, length = 67.

Another situation, caused by random anchor tags scattered throughout:

```html
Did anyone outside the Vale even suspect where Catelyn <a></a>Stark had taken him?
```

Again, searching for "Catelyn Stark" needs to include the HTML, so location = 47, length = 20.

I have been able to get around it temporarily by adding those specific cases (searching for "Catelyn <a></a>Stark specifically), but clearly I should have a more robust solution, which I cannot seem to get my head around. My attempts have been using RegEx but with limited success.
I have found various questions regarding HTML matching/stripping (and whether or not to use RegEx =)), but this case seems to be somewhat unique.
Stripping the tags isn't an option as the content must be preserved.
This is within a stand-alone C# application.
Any ideas, steps in the right direction, or similar examples should your search go better than mine would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why can't you use the `IndexOf` Mehtod and `SubString()` Method and the `Length` method..???

Comment: What are you doing with the location and length information?

Comment: Ugh. Regular expressions are so not suited for html parsing...granted, you're not explicitly parsing html here, but you might as well be. Best advice I could give would be to augment your expression to include some greedy look ahead match for any "tag", that is, from less-than to greater than.

Comment: Unless you make the question more generic and applicable to broader context I'm afraid it is "too localized". Also please explain why do you need Regex even if you failed to use it and found reasoning why ability to use Regex for HTML parsing ranges from "theoretically impossible" to "limited to non-generic HTML in very well known format".

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear, but I do not specifically need a regular expression to match it, that was just my initial feeling of what to try. Any appropriate solution will work.
The location and length info is used to highlight the character within the excerpt on another device, which requires that the HTML be included

Comment: How would you handle the case where the search string only matches part of the text inside of a tag, i.e., `<span height="-0em"><font size="7">Daenerys Targaryen wed</font></span>` with a search string of `Daenerys Targaryn`?  Would that include the closing tags, or just leave them out?  Or are the tags only ever going to be around 1 character or empty?

Comment: If you are using it to highlight characters (as I suspected), it may be way easier to do this with JavaScript, because you can work with the parsed DOM rather than having to muck around with the source HTML.  Is that an option, or does this have to be server-side?

Comment: In that case there, "Daenerys Targaryen" is in there verbatim, so it would just match that section. location = 35, length = 18.
This is a standalone C# application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible approach would be to insert the following between each letter in your search string:

```
(?:<[^>]*>)*
```

So when searching for the character "Bran" your regex would become the following:

```
(?:<[^>]*>)*B(?:<[^>]*>)*r(?:<[^>]*>)*a(?:<[^>]*>)*n
```

This will allow your regex to match any number of HTML tags anywhere within the search string.  Note that this will only work if your search strings are always something simple like a character's name, and not regular expressions (this method will fail if there is repetition like `a*` in your search string).

Comment: I was hoping for something a bit more elegant, but this may have to do for now! Thanks

Comment: This ended up working quite well.  
`string pattern = "(?:<[^>]*>)*";  
pattern = string.Format("{0}{1}{0}", pattern, string.Join(pattern, s.AsEnumerable()));`  
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I would create a function that would take "Daenerys Targaryn" as a parameter and then strip the first letter.  Then, it would only search for "aenerys Targaryn," and if found, it would search for ">D<" or the first variable letter.  Does than make sense?

Example:

```
public static string searchFor(string str)
{
  // strip first letter of search string (in this case "D")
  // search for the rest of the string ("aenerys Targaryn")
  // if found, search for ">D<"
  // if found, search for HTML tags with "D" inside (using regex)
  // if found, search for HTML tags with the previous HTML tag in them (using regex)
  return result;
}
```

Comment: That could likely work for the first-letter cases. I may try that F.J's solution does not work in all cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well using Javascript or Php you can get the text of elements and the text of documents and search there and then do a regex to return the closest match (containing the html):

#### Another option:

---

would be to index the books first using something like Lucene Search Engine (which happens to let you index in different formats (html format being one of them).

You can then use the Lucene api to search your documents a little easier.
In php we have [Zend_Search_Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.search.lucene.html) which works perfectly for this kind of thing.

---

Lucene Search can be found at:
http://lucene.apache.org/core/

Have fun!

Comment: Also zend search lucene lets you setup keys that area searchable.

Comment: The indexed format can be structured how you like and then searched based on keys.  Take a look at the zend_search_lucene api to understand how it works cause it sounds like optimal solution for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Unfortunately I am using C# in a standalone application, so I cannot use any javascript or php libraries. Thanks though!

Comment: Lucene search is available for most languages look it up for c#.  I searched and found http://lucenenet.apache.org/ (a port for c#).  Give it a look the lucene search engine is pretty powerful, has been around for a long time, and has been tried in tested in many a project.

Comment: Also just found lucene example on stack that uses c# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004849/lucene-net-search-results.  Good luck.